# Intellij PyCharm/Idea/etc: how to add a toolbar button that runs a shell script?

Tags: shell, intellij-idea, button, pycharm, toolbar

In Intellij IDE's such as PyCharm or Idea there is an option to customize the menu and toolbar by right-clicking the toolbar and picking **Customize menus and toolbars**. While it is possible to select almost any IDE action there doesn't seem to be a way to add a button that runs a custom shell script. The only way to run a shell script seems to be by adding a **Run Configuration** of type *Shell Script* and then invoking it via the **Run** button, but is there a way to have multiple clickable buttons on the toolbar that would run arbitrary shell commands? (no need for an actual console)

Answer (score 2):

In Jetbrains jargon this is called an ***external tool*** and is configured under <kbd>Preferences -> Tools -> External Tools</kbd>.

Once you added the commands you need as external tools you can add them as toolbar buttons by right-clicking the toolbar and picking *Customize menus and toolbars*, expand the node under the Main Toolbar, click <kbd>➕</kbd> to add an item and then type `external` in the search box to select your "external tools" and optionally set custom icons for them.